# how to generate 10000 random no. in a range 30,40

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I have issue i want to generate 10000 random float no's in a given range, I cannot use random module because it will always go out of my range

x=random.randrange(30.000000,40.000000,10000)

i tried this

and i'm exepcting 10,000 random float no. b/w them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `random.uniform` like:

```py
import random
x = [random.uniform(30.0, 40.0) for i in range(10000)]
```

Alternatively, you could use `numpy` like:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.uniform(30.0, 40.0, 10000)
```

NB:
The second option would give you an `ndarray`, which is normally fine, but if your program requires you to have a list instead, you can just do this instead:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.uniform(30.0, 40.0, 10000).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `random.uniform`:

```
for i in range(10000):
    random.uniform(30.0, 40.0)
```

I see you're trying to assign the float values to x, you can do so with:

```
x = []
for i in range(10000):
    x.append(random.uniform(30.0, 40.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html):

```
x = np.random.uniform(30.000000, 40.000000, 10000)
```

---

```
array([35.8284953 , 36.31252488, 37.0409413 , ..., 39.07939188,
       33.76935076, 31.11123249])
```